# Bounding below Hausdorff measure of connected set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm trying to prove that for every connected set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$, $H^1(E)$, the Hausdorff measure is bounded below by $\text{diam}(E)$.

[In the answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186574/hausdorff-measure-of-rectifiable-curve-equal-to-its-length), it was suggested to use a Lipschitz mapping defined by $x\mapsto d(x,a)$. How does it prove the inequality $H^1(E)\ge\text{diam}(E)$?

Comment: If $E \subset \mathbb R$ is connected it is an interval and its diameter is its length. Are you looking to prove that the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of an interval is not less than its length, or are you looking for something more general?